# Searching for substrings in large text document?

Tags: string-manipulation, text

I have a large text file that I need to search for certain substrings and I would like to use the speed-up that `TextSearch` gives. Unfortunately, with `TextSearch` queries will only match *entire* words:

```
f = Export["~/test.txt", "1234 1234"];
TextSearch[CreateSearchIndex@f, SearchQueryString["*23*"]]
```

[image]

I'd prefer not to use `StringCases` as it is very slow on the large document. Is there some way around this?

Comment: Is it not `Import`?

Comment: And then after import...

Comment: Try maybe `"23~"` as the search string. `~` is supposed to indicate a close but non-exact match. It does work in your simple case, but I don't know how well it would perform on a real example.

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`SearchQueryString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SearchQueryString.html) in [`TextSearch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextSearch.html).

```
f = Export["~/test.txt", "helloworld"];
TextSearch[CreateSearchIndex@f, SearchQueryString["hello*"]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Edmund! See my update, we've almost got it I think